# Any idea why Cachix isn't working for me on macOS?

Tags: ihp

This is using Nix 2.15.0 and IHP 1.0.1 on macOS. Despite running `cachix use digitallyinduced`, it still wants to build 131 packages using GHC, which takes forever! Any idea why?

```
✗ cachix use digitallyinduced
Configured https://digitallyinduced.cachix.org binary cache in <home>/.config/nix/nix.conf
✗ ./start                    
these 131 derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/057syi1w7i5hsa7j04dlxwn7kq74ylr1-primitive-unaligned-0.1.1.1.drv
  /nix/store/07y8385xblbcpzgqvwpxps774b5899vn-http-media-0.8.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/0av5ga9873pb379avhalpq3as911xj40-resource-pool-0.2.3.2.drv
  /nix/store/sr5jx01sss10pzi73r9gqdf5kbxqxjrd-wai-extra-3.1.12.1.drv
  /nix/store/5fd7p41y97vz2dmjlfxbqvyav0m0xn13-hspec-wai-0.11.1.drv
  /nix/store/wc4indwz374wrr7z72lp00yyjm35h3zq-nats-1.1.2.drv
  /nix/store/0r8w28sxxv9fna679vbakv5kvkylb8vd-scotty-0.12.drv
  /nix/store/a55b3vi1p0ini7bv7b223q05r02hwh0j-deferred-folds-0.9.18.2.drv
  /nix/store/wxgnnrjpx8qpbibyk5vfx7j3dphw413n-focus-1.0.3.drv
  /nix/store/b1kiric1sfrq90z614abxj8r8kgawvx3-primitive-extras-0.10.1.5.drv
  /nix/store/19y0nzdlmsn6m35q0jgfdg052v9v7lzz-stm-hamt-1.2.0.7.drv
  /nix/store/sa02jhvbs2rajrc8xjfnj409fbxprxwh-stm-containers-1.2.drv
  /nix/store/335pbnkrillrdacq519fm6hhrijs7qzw-hls-graph-1.7.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/fifxgs7qyv9i0cdf8saa3cw08frpppc0-lsp-1.4.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/760cv420mxkl8bard6xy6w8krsy5m81f-hls-plugin-api-1.4.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/77s93z2mvp6x5gdl2d25v4f66bnxwgyf-hiedb-0.4.1.0.drv
  /nix/store/n4p3kszidcqg2lzd30h56x7qvdsz3r7p-tree-diff-0.2.1.1.drv
  /nix/store/df1ssb40s0cn0hwwd3i5qf4h4fj1lkrb-haddock-library-1.10.0.drv
  /nix/store/pxrc1csnw2h90hj9jz72q7vf5x3q70a2-lsp-test-0.14.0.2.drv
  /nix/store/vg5a7a1dfs31nnpddwrjajnsam54ixba-retrie-1.2.0.1.drv
  /nix/store/fmz6jz044nk3wv2dsy1gz8vib1wj9fdx-ghcide-1.7.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/0xj1lnp5gnhgc2kdf34czafpkmh8db7k-hls-alternate-number-format-plugin-1.1.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/146a926sa4xfd35q4gxhixw7k5zckgrq-tasty-discover-4.2.4.drv
  /nix/store/1639ygg0v3brvcvgxxxkiw0lvs45jbp8-hfsevents-0.1.6.drv
  /nix/store/n3ihxchvrbhgf3hwjgr06l1pnpalyj4j-wide-word-0.1.1.2.drv
  /nix/store/1kbclnzjfqnkfwxh6rqly6xdpcjj4v54-byte-order-0.1.3.0.drv
  /nix/store/1kj13dwm4ffl8h8rmlgrdb6y1s144n3k-basic-prelude-0.7.0.drv
  /nix/store/1n4ca8y0b2n092sl18k3libqr2q3qyzk-hls-floskell-plugin-1.0.1.1.drv
  /nix/store/1nnw3m8pjkbxk6ywsgh0ckv2cvvyg3kf-ormolu-0.5.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/hpwxsqg2mmbdqgv87a654nn5zhhzl4g5-hspec-contrib-0.5.1.drv
  /nix/store/rkkn2h6vwg0c8ln7x9x2ifnz0wfkbjbq-enclosed-exceptions-1.0.3.drv
  /nix/store/1vmar1drdwrqlk4aai27vgw8zn777pc5-shelly-1.10.0.drv
  /nix/store/274iymv723rk14v8b1vmjwzpdwynn98w-string-conversions-0.4.0.1.drv
  /nix/store/2hbrdm8mimd4ylpgh4zk4i3r7l9biwgw-fsnotify-0.3.0.1.drv
  /nix/store/2jimayyjyx09xbb9p45zxnwjfjb338xy-base-unicode-symbols-0.2.4.2.drv
  /nix/store/2m9vldw97f576qcq0hmcfgvqidn0dg79-hls-qualify-imported-names-plugin-1.0.1.0.drv
  /nix/store/33wgplzj247vaqm8n9zlwn8slkpn8b03-ini-0.4.1.drv
  /nix/store/rhvq25xi2frpd4shp63wir70ym68n8d5-byteable-0.1.1.drv
  /nix/store/5qnw4jlgi2mj5xbrfpjvbj5ngggji6fy-securemem-0.1.10.drv
  /nix/store/m1j2wv8q6yb02yhq9k84rf8v0aam3n8c-crypto-cipher-types-0.0.9.drv
  /nix/store/s8z37a6scy8phgspiha4mgfzq2q1ij16-crypto-cipher-tests-0.0.11.drv
  /nix/store/dib0acdw2px5vc16ncb3sg8nhacd5vlx-cipher-aes-0.2.11.drv
  /nix/store/qmk47yv77g9v67rfhmlqwrpzyxs8gmvs-crypto-random-0.0.9.drv
  /nix/store/3cf12ichc5cs9pr0hd5w9wn5lkihs20b-cprng-aes-0.6.1.drv
  /nix/store/5jxin0l72ig0jgp8nqy26a7cq5l1arz3-ghc-tcplugins-extra-0.4.2.drv
  /nix/store/zcnnaa91nnn27750ddql4z12raqs3z47-ghc-typelits-natnormalise-0.7.6.drv
  /nix/store/vp1gdn19rmry84crwcrg87lb5ln52ag5-ghc-typelits-knownnat-0.7.6.drv
  /nix/store/w2j4msfnl1dbszhz174b9agacj1pjngs-hspec-hedgehog-0.0.1.2.drv
  /nix/store/3q40v7pwl5jb9i5awkh50mwd1b4x49ib-typerep-map-0.5.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/3y945wgc794p7kq6irvsd17apvh56hb6-hls-pragmas-plugin-1.0.2.1.drv
  /nix/store/53j943s3f5lm596zsdbfarf2yj6nxl47-postgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3.drv
  /nix/store/5npisr73jgykzhrv0nhnp7i184yqzyrc-hls-rename-plugin-1.0.0.2.drv
  /nix/store/8d352n2ycy492xzpr9y31vmpmr6viv5h-errors-2.3.0.drv
  /nix/store/a2v84vx068h2na7craykndbn4p9sqjap-wai-session-0.3.3.drv
  /nix/store/sj3wm6a1xbhsk6kqpc67v8d35cy40ywz-crypto-api-0.13.3.drv
  /nix/store/lalmhx5mbjcy38a42sfaxnc39sdb3b09-skein-1.0.9.4.drv
  /nix/store/vj3znsk2l01w7mwrc3gs75kywqfdwidc-clientsession-0.9.1.2.drv
  /nix/store/5vsnif5x1zbv3gcdsqxm00rk9dikl2km-wai-session-clientsession-0.1.drv
  /nix/store/5yvrlphgxg5ii07mlzr0fp65cvkpjz7a-stringbuilder-0.5.1.drv
  /nix/store/6jxwwwpyp6ym88pxd3hlgwjdk9lp21df-atomic-primops-0.8.4.drv
  /nix/store/8818fksv9qlcmb099bsg9zdpsl5w1hwy-unagi-chan-0.4.1.4.drv
  /nix/store/8k94cfvfh4ajlmfz3g4z4wavislihnwq-wai-cors-0.2.7.drv
  /nix/store/9a08niaxy06610pvgp8f4mm9cj0hyyal-postgresql-simple-0.6.4.drv
  /nix/store/shkhbvlxnx1kqwp078cmj7qlywidl6lz-websockets-0.12.7.3.drv
  /nix/store/sndwl3c96bp6lqfiq3505d2gp43zbxq3-wai-app-static-3.1.7.4.drv
  /nix/store/aq7yc2c9r0n62rn40xzia2p9qavsy45l-wai-websockets-3.0.1.2.drv
  /nix/store/w83z0air5v26yp14bsi4ddvi7v349b36-http-accept-0.2.drv
  /nix/store/ard0g71kw96a7k3w1ckw3vmd1aagj2k9-wai-util-0.8.drv
  /nix/store/qqq44p9nigwp198mirn1m7vwzr6ap2xy-hspec-expectations-lifted-0.10.0.drv
  /nix/store/rnzh47xal5k6ci2fcn1i12qirf40f1sn-expiring-cache-map-0.0.6.1.drv
  /nix/store/c8cfyv4zs7147q4ld730n2yxwicgbzrn-wai-middleware-static-0.9.2.drv
  /nix/store/lcvwn81dyaimvr8k5das5qc6qpzw7hf9-natural-arithmetic-0.1.3.0.drv
  /nix/store/a28a1rhwnppasr1jil4ibls8zaw54ayf-run-st-0.1.1.0.drv
  /nix/store/vgiy2cz2wkpw8s2rdnpyhiyjkvxsm5n1-tuples-0.1.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/sq7dny0g6zmbaaq8k23xagrpfcwa5xjb-byteslice-0.2.7.0.drv
  /nix/store/zd7w8xs2a2abqbb8bwcnd55gs8421bin-contiguous-0.6.2.0.drv
  /nix/store/p50zjhq9sgy7a90a5i3w80kw118lyfjm-bytesmith-0.3.9.0.drv
  /nix/store/k5ldbv2ch8j0ck4x24my1n6ai7qyqkwl-primitive-offset-0.2.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/rz82nk4dvbx9wfma9mlxdcgn2lzxykga-zigzag-0.0.1.0.drv
  /nix/store/rd691lwj1vq1p4rlawsywi41d6ni7jdk-bytebuild-0.3.11.0.drv
  /nix/store/vq3p0ww700g56rp12cangrfpxffiml0x-word-compat-0.0.4.drv
  /nix/store/d3ymd15pbggr53ag8j795lxkvkgjz6vb-ip-1.7.5.drv
  /nix/store/cg107mwjbsxaplfmhpkzayfn64a8skn8-cryptohash-0.11.9.drv
  /nix/store/hs23hlqcbhn33gcar0dmkl1gsjagcw9m-pwstore-fast-2.4.4.drv
  /nix/store/ks8df551vqvjcp4p5f7zbdxrrlcqc88i-inflections-0.4.0.6.drv
  /nix/store/jp171kiya7ilnxa0lziqrl7a59bp62kz-xml-types-0.3.8.drv
  /nix/store/jpk5nhsyck9q6697dffs7bff0c91sa2m-xml-conduit-1.9.1.1.drv
  /nix/store/l4pjgksycyr6hbhccgj3jb43hm2xq5kx-mime-mail-0.5.1.drv
  /nix/store/ky33b74mxzbqci1x8g87r696m09myjnc-mime-mail-ses-0.4.3.drv
  /nix/store/lmw1czggzakdj7ix6i7a0l2xz5k2qy9k-neat-interpolation-0.5.1.3.drv
  /nix/store/96a6if5vlm2h4d73v2z9ry9s7kmadzh6-relude-1.1.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/a90c6iwv5c1h5xclya03na4rfbdp2pyq-digest-0.0.1.3.drv
  /nix/store/gv7ldaax463plpan5xy3ad8z1zh8q6za-conduit-combinators-1.3.0.drv
  /nix/store/q6s1fniiv68fcwd5hmhrs25g2xgvyfjb-cryptonite-conduit-0.2.2.drv
  /nix/store/pp4rz2sqcz7i3ncyf5zvqslbwr4pj4yk-minio-hs-1.6.0.drv
  /nix/store/qla5qjc166zmxwfy4vrf0xmczahc7vv8-smtp-mail-0.3.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/bp82v3vrd51ixy9qrnzn43inxyas4icq-regex-pcre-builtin-0.95.2.3.8.44.drv
  /nix/store/pahhnn0gnf0nx6j5q6qz1fdwkxw3n9v6-pcre-utils-0.1.8.2.drv
  /nix/store/r5v6h5ccyzzncyg32mxk8bpgf9v9wnn8-countable-inflections-0.3.0.drv
  /nix/store/rrkxkrxiiaha9rnjdid9rnzkjvgqprdz-random-strings-0.1.1.0.drv
  /nix/store/8k6ix0pa7yca55c0jnglnrwdjdw4izzn-say-0.1.0.1.drv
  /nix/store/mmxal2jdh4ywdpzr1bm8fhnc8f5jas0y-dlist-instances-0.1.1.1.drv
  /nix/store/cz6k1n72qav9iy9xa8xqmnn505kbya4b-mono-traversable-instances-0.1.1.0.drv
  /nix/store/f5lhw2ra5c5ayhhl83irr3j7swnaqh9m-stm-chans-3.0.0.6.drv
  /nix/store/kb84qixwqz8hx2lk7cwiq9x3vrkrshbk-chunked-data-0.3.1.drv
  /nix/store/yb95nlvzchdp0xc0h8a443i8qj14qn6d-mutable-containers-0.3.4.drv
  /nix/store/vxv1vhdzn7lr3ajy9kkmr57a7i5gr5ih-classy-prelude-1.5.0.2.drv
  /nix/store/vgmypqj0ywkwwwbd4r3dchpix388xfy6-ihp-hsx-v1.0.1.drv
  /nix/store/dlwcs2gy62wi5p2rv1f99iv3zhiipbp3-markdown-unlit-0.5.1.drv
  /nix/store/s1242s2wsglmxhqffghwzp8yh9asn1sq-th-env-0.1.1.drv
  /nix/store/w7nc1s8ad2gakac9sy6jyd7zwzw6vmsa-with-utf8-1.0.2.3.drv
  /nix/store/fc41qvw38gw6m23j60jiag26gc4jcdrx-time-locale-compat-0.1.1.5.drv
  /nix/store/nik8f0fv5aspalzg1szpzbfmmlias8rp-crypto-pubkey-types-0.4.3.drv
  /nix/store/wwf982jsz0lshdvwpfpn9qs7gzprj5mi-RSA-2.4.1.drv
  /nix/store/ha2rr1bwcglq846fnarnv0sqxy1393py-authenticate-oauth-1.7.drv
  /nix/store/yqb3xb6zzihpfz3ahm8gd37qqabfqp2x-wreq-0.5.3.3.drv
  /nix/store/yx8gbcpbjlz61pdv0akg8gajvp7kz863-cereal-text-0.1.0.2.drv
  /nix/store/6n6qjvfabwisjm2s5is737d19i29ch6s-ihp-v1.0.1.drv
  /nix/store/9xvf4i4cinaccmpqwkcyp732xgliihfl-hls-ormolu-plugin-1.0.2.1.drv
  /nix/store/d62vjxdfigp2ki2wvwxk21xgrdmdjb1d-hls-change-type-signature-plugin-1.0.1.0.drv
  /nix/store/gaaigffvzh982nkcb3nzc48kfyp1yrvv-hls-eval-plugin-1.2.2.0.drv
  /nix/store/gz0qvr31r1dl8wgx83ykm5bvg9ga2g53-fourmolu-0.6.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/kd270jy2jcl9c7w77v2jpab410xd2hhg-hls-fourmolu-plugin-1.0.3.0.drv
  /nix/store/mnmwyxl2l4h648b926z9krb1zrwrxsyc-hls-class-plugin-1.0.3.0.drv
  /nix/store/npd6cncmj5hw9l4ksn88cb82b4visr1z-hls-explicit-imports-plugin-1.1.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/v920lk759s2svilwg3lhhmplzn90cfcq-hls-module-name-plugin-1.0.2.0.drv
  /nix/store/vxxxflyk7qnvipzp6bfw6lv5xwwlwrff-hls-refine-imports-plugin-1.0.2.0.drv
  /nix/store/yfrxkjzsxra04fip4lm1m9isyvp2747y-hls-selection-range-plugin-1.0.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/z63qvfxh8y9zslhfkxvmz44r7n6x2gbi-hls-call-hierarchy-plugin-1.0.3.0.drv
  /nix/store/kyc9yb26yqiyxhhzn6k0abypian9hwpg-haskell-language-server-1.7.0.0.drv
  /nix/store/vay8dq9nxx03v3pph3x3976j04ppj0in-ghc-9.2.4-with-packages.drv
these 5 paths will be fetched (29.54 MiB download, 261.02 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/ainh32alirqbm0g2rhknf6lrsnb1bzii-hie-bios-0.9.1
  /nix/store/kb2fl8lczfs42nc8f5s4vahrlhxfllf9-hlint-3.4.1
  /nix/store/kripz5d0s0mv668byjm9r5ai66i3qz7s-implicit-hie-0.1.2.7
  /nix/store/al73yayvy41327ag38skxqyjpbasjdly-implicit-hie-cradle-0.5.0.0
  /nix/store/mfqh58jcmvnan6s8w67vb44k0mwzwh5m-lsp-types-1.4.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's possible that some of the packages that need to be built are not available in the `digitallyinduced` cache, and therefore Nix needs to build them from source, so please check which packages are being built like this(running this command will display a list of packages that need to be built, as well as their dependencies) :

```
nix why-depends --all --requisites --include-outputs $(nix-instantiate --eval ./default.nix | tr -d '"')
```

You can also find a list of Nix binary caches at [https://nixcache.reflex-framewo‌​rk.org.](https://nixcache.reflex-framewo%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Brk.org)